# How do i call a stored procedure with parameters from c# code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have created a stored procedure shown below ,how will i call this from c# code behind to get the result and results are stored in dataset.

```
USE [Test]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[tesproc]    Script Date: 09/01/2010 13:00:54 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[tesproc]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @a float, @b float, @c float,@d int
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    select Id, Name1,ZipCode,StreetName,StreetNumber,State1,Lat,Lng,  ( 6371 * ACOS( COS( (@a/@b) ) * COS(  (Lat/@b)  ) * COS( ( Lng/@b ) - (@c/@b) )  + SIN( @a/@b ) * SIN(  Lat/@b  ) ) ) as distance from business_details where ( 6371 * ACOS( COS( (@a/@b) ) * COS(  (Lat/@b)  ) * COS( ( Lng/@b ) - (@c/@b) )  + SIN( @a/@b ) * SIN(  Lat/@b  ) ) )<@d
END
```

If i execute this stored procedure in sql server its working fine with this following call

```
exec dbo.tesproc 12.9216667 ,57.2958,77.591667,1
```

Comment: Have you seen http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/AdoDotNet/Lesson07.aspx? Simple Google search for "Calling Stored Procedure from ADO.net" will give you all the info that you need!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("connection string goes here"))
using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("tesproc", conn))
{
    comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", 0.1);
    // etc

    conn.Open();

    using (SqlDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            int id = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("id"));
            // etc
        }
    }
}
```

There are lots of comprehensive samples on the internet:

http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/AdoDotNet/Lesson04.aspx

My code sample is just demonstrating what it might look like - it was written straight in the editor so may not work on its own.

Answer (score 1):

Look into [`SqlConnection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.aspx) and [`SqlCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx).